# How to monitor website stats from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, ssh, openssh, sshfs

is there any way to monitoring the stats from my own website .. like example.com .. just via our terminal without installing plugins .. so we can see real time visitor and bots came and go at website .. what im means i dont need to go to my cpanel to see who came and who are leaving here the photos that i hope i saw the stats at my terminal

[image]

Comment: I think the host must support fetching data using some client, if not, then it it alsmost impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Enable ssh access for your web server (you can do this through the host gator control panel).  I am going to assume you are using apache and you would run tail -f /var/log/access.log.  Doing this will follow the file so to speak and instantly print to the shell when you have a new visitor to your web server.

Access.log has all the user agent, resource access, request type information, etc... that I see in the host gator screenshot above.

EDIT: This answer assumes you have a VPS or dedicated server.  I haven't used and unable to find any information for shared hosting.

Comment: oh man so is there any possible to use as offline not live monitoring ? but still via ssh in terminal

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean. I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can access outside the cpanel using [Awstats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWStats), to configuration Awstats on ubuntu you can see http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/16/configuring-awstats-on-ubuntu-server/